# .NET event raising and NullObject pattern

Tags: c#, .net, events, design-patterns

We can raise event in two ways:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;

private void DoSomething()
{
    ...
    var handler = MyEvent;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this,EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

and

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent = (o,e) => {} ;

private void DoSomething()
{
    ...
    MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

I prefer the last one. It is shorter.
My colleagues insist on the first variant.

**Is there any superiority of the first over the second one?**

Comment: You can at least simplify the first to `if (this.MyEvent != null) this.MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);`

Comment: @JonB: Wrong; that isn't thread-safe.

Comment: how are you going to prevent the class from setting the event to null?

Comment: @Jon no, you shouldn't. That can cause a race condition, see [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx)

Comment: @JonB Only in case of single threaded context. Otherwise variable is needed

Comment: [cringe]... I need to go fix some code

Comment: The only possible one I can think of is that it avoids an unneeded initialisation step.

Comment: If some code sets the event to null, the second variant raises null exceptions.

Comment: @namerehe Why and when should the class set explicitly null to the event?

Comment: @voroninp well, thats the only problem i might see.

Comment: @voroninp, it is clear that the event could be set to null, as that is the reason for having the var handler = MyEvent; threading protection in place.

Comment: @voroninp@Justin Harvey  i dont think that will ever occur in regular(aka non spaghetti) code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update for C# 6**

In C# 6 you simply use the null-conditional operator like so:

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
```

This is [recommended by the Roslyn wiki](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#null-conditional-operators)

**Original Answer**

Eric Lippert has [a great blog post on Events and Races](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx), which you should read if you haven't.

The first option could be considered safer than the second because the event could get set to null. Someone could carelessly modify the class. Also, if you deserialize instances the 2nd method won't work (depending on the serialization mechanism you use).

I sometimes use a helper method to raise events

```
static class Raiser
{
    public static void Raise<T>(this EventHandler<T> evnt, object sender, T args)
        where T : EventArgs
    {
        if (evnt != null)
        {
            evnt(sender, args);
        }
    }
}

class SomeClass
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent;

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        MyEvent.Raise(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Best of both worlds and a good use of extenstion methods, gets my orange arrow.

Comment: Nice helper method. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with your arguments but I interested about 'careless modification'. Does it mean I should check ANY variable in a method which can accidentally be changed somewhere else in the code? I thought it was Code Contracts' invariants for such a purpose.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't consider careless modification a reason to favor option 1 over option 2, but your colleagues might :)